# Search and replace with finding if L or R is a prefix or suffix or nothing

Tags: python, regex

Please excuse me for posting this again, but I think I really screwed up my previous thread. Because of comment blocks only allow so many characters, I could not explain myself better, and I did not see a choice for replying so that I would have more room. So if nobody minds, let me try explaining everything that I need. Basically I need to flip the names of 3D objects that have a prefix or a suffix of "L" or "R" from:

1: "L" with "R", 
2: "R" with "L", or 
3: don't change.

This is for a script in Maya in order to duplicate selected objects and flip there names. I got the duplicating part down packed and now it is about trying to flip the names of the duplicated objects based on 5 possibilities. Starting with the first 2 prefixes, the duplicated objects need to start with either

```
"L_" or "R_", match case doesn't matter.
```

The next 2, the suffixes, need to be either:

```
"_L" or "_R" with a possible extra character "_", such as "Finger_L_001".
```

Now in a search on this forum, I think found something almost to what I am looking for. I copied the syntax and replaced the user's search characters with mine being "L_" and "*L", just to see if it would work, but with only some expectation. Since I only know the basics of regular expressions, such as "L*.*" will find L_Finger_001, I really do not understand this line of syntax below and why the second choice is not leaving it as L_Finger. 
So maybe this is not what I need or is it? And can someone explain this? I tried searching for keywords such as (?P) and (?P\S+), but I did not find anything. So without further due, here is the syntax....

```
>>> x = re.sub(r'(?P<prefix>_L)(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|L_)','\g<key>',"L_Finger")
>>> x
'L_Finger'
>>> x = re.sub(r'(?P<prefix>L_)?(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|_L)','\g<key>',"L_anything")
>>> x
'Finger'
```

#

> > Updated 11\10\13 3:52 PM ET
> >     Ok, so I have tweaked the code a bit, but I like where this is going. Actually, my original idea was to use dictionaries, but I could figure out how to search. By kobejohn steering me in the right direction with defining all possibilities, this is starting to make sense. Here is a WIP

```
samples = ('L_Arm',
           'R_Arm',
           'Arm_L',
           'Arm_R',
           'IndexFinger_L_001',
           'IndexFinger_R_001',
           '_LArm')

prefix_l, prefix_r = 'L_', 'R_'
suffix_l, suffix_lIndex, suffix_r, suffix_rIndex = '_L', '_L_', '_R', '_R_'

prefix_replace = {prefix_l: prefix_r, prefix_r: prefix_l}
suffix_replace = {suffix_l: suffix_r, suffix_r: suffix_l}
suffixIndex_replace = {suffix_lIndex: suffix_rIndex, suffix_rIndex: suffix_lIndex}

results = dict()
for sample in samples:
    # Default value is no modification - may be replaced below
    results[sample] = sample

    # Handle prefixes
    prefix = prefix_replace.get(sample[:2].upper())
    if prefix :
        result = prefix+sample[:2]

    else :
        #handle the suffixes
        suffix_partition = sample.rpartition("_")
        result = suffix_partition[0] if suffix_partition[2].isdigit() else sample
        suffix = suffix_replace.get(result[-2:])
        print("Before: %s --> After: %s"%(sample, suffix))
```

Comment: Could you add some example inputs/outputs? That would make your post a lot easier to follow.

Comment: @Dogbert the code block above is my trial example of all I could think of.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. You mean examples of object names. For example: original prefix object name: 'code L_Arm flipped to R_Arm' or suffix: 'code Arm_L flipped to Arm_R'. Another possibility that is allowed, suffix: 'code IndexFinger_L_001 flipped to IndexFinger_R_001'. A wrong answer, which means don't change, Could be a prefix of 'code _LArm' Yes true "L", is in the prefix, but in my case 'code _L' is suffix. Does that makes things clearer?

Comment: @user2971953 Agreed with Dogbert. Please make a list of at least 5 (since you said there are 5 cases) input strings and the exact output strings you expect.

Comment: @kobejohn I think we had posted at the same time. The comment above yours, are my examples

Comment: I do not like this forums format. I really wish we could have the option to post **FULL** replies

Comment: @user2971953 Please put all of your examples in a complete table into your question. I'm still a little unclear. For example 'code L_Arm' --> 'R_Arm'? What happened to 'code'?

Comment: @kobejohn What happened to code? isn't 'code blah blah' the format for using code blocks?

Comment: @user2971953 Ooooh. No. in-line code blocks are done with the "grave" character (under the ~ character on an English keyboard) before and after the code. `<-- there is a grave before this gray text and there is one after it -->`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess multiple regular expressions is valid too. Here is a way using re's similar to the ones you found. It assumes real prefixes (nothing before the prefix) and pseudo-suffixes (anywhere except the first characters). Below that is a parsing solution with the same assumptions.

```
import re

samples = ('L_Arm',
           'R_Arm',
           'Arm_L',
           'Arm_R',
           'IndexFinger_L_001',
           'IndexFinger_R_001',
           '_LArm')
re_with_subs = ((r'(?P<prefix>L_)(?P<poststring>\S+)',
                 r'R_\g<poststring>'),
                (r'(?P<prefix>R_)(?P<poststring>\S+)',
                 r'L_\g<poststring>'),
                (r'(?P<prestring>\S+)(?P<suffix>_L)(?P<poststring>\S*)',
                 r'\g<prestring>_R\g<poststring>'),
                (r'(?P<prestring>\S+)(?P<suffix>_R)(?P<poststring>\S*)',
                 r'\g<prestring>_L\g<poststring>'))
results_re = dict()
for sample in samples:
    # Default value is no modification - may be replaced below
    results_re[sample] = sample
    for pattern, substitution in re_with_subs:
        result = re.sub(pattern, substitution, sample)
        if result != sample:
            results_re[sample] = result
            break  # only allow one substitution per string

for original, result in results_re.items():
    print('{0} --> {1}'.format(original, result))
```

Here is the parsing solution.

```
samples = ('L_Arm',
           'R_Arm',
           'Arm_L',
           'Arm_R',
           'IndexFinger_L_001',
           'IndexFinger_R_001',
           '_LArm')

prefix_l, prefix_r = 'L_', 'R_'
suffix_l, suffix_r = '_L', '_R'
prefix_replacement = {prefix_l: prefix_r,
                      prefix_r: prefix_l}
suffix_replacement = {suffix_l: suffix_r,
                      suffix_r: suffix_l}
results = dict()
for sample in samples:
    # Default value is no modification - may be replaced below
    results[sample] = sample
    # Handle prefixes
    prefix = sample[:2].upper()
    try:
        results[sample] = prefix_replacement[prefix] + sample[2:]
        continue  # assume no suffixes if a prefix found
    except KeyError:
        pass  # no valid prefix
    # Handle pseudo-suffixes
    start = None
    for valid_suffix in (suffix_l, suffix_r):
        try:
            start = sample.upper().rindex(valid_suffix, 1)
            break  # stop if valid suffix found
        except ValueError:
            pass
    if not start is None:
        suffix = sample[start: start + 2].upper()
        new_suffix = suffix_replacement[suffix]
        results[sample] = sample[:start] + new_suffix + sample[start + 2:]

for original, result in results.items():
    print('{0} --> {1}'.format(original, result))
```

gives the result:

- L_Arm --> R_Arm
- R_Arm --> L_Arm
- IndexFinger_L_001 --> IndexFinger_R_001
- Arm_L --> Arm_R
- _LArm --> _LArm
- IndexFinger_R_001 --> IndexFinger_L_001
- Arm_R --> Arm_L

Comment: I was only putting the word "'code...'" in front of the words thinking that stood for code block. So from the looks of things, I think you understand exactly what I am looking for, but I do not want to mark this answered as of yet

Comment: Note to all: As I still might need help, I wanted to update what is going on but this forum is so difficult to use. I do not know why this forum only supports comment blocks and you cannot make them as lengthy as you need them to be. So instead, I just edit my top post and added onto it. If anyone is interested, I marked a note in my original post showing where it has been updated. Thanks

Comment: @user2971953 It's better not to think of SO as a forum. Comments are for very short additions/corrections/clarifications. If there is information important to your question, you should edit the original question for all future users. If the answer gave you basically what you need, you should probably accept it or update the question with a clear description of what is not working / what you can't figure out. [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a place for reviewing and improving working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this tricky regex pattern >>

```
if re.search('(^[LR]_|_[LR](_|$))', str):
    str = re.sub(r'(^[LR](?=_)|(?<=_)[LR](?=(?:_|...$)))(.*)(?=.*\1(.))...$',
                 r'\3\2', str+"LRL")
```

See this **[demo](http://ideone.com/LRX4gt)**.

---

Alternatively, you can do it by one line code >>

```
str = re.sub(r'(^[LR](?=_)|(?<=_)[LR](?=(?:_|...$)))(.*)(?=.*\1(.))...$', r'\3\2', str+"LRL")[:len(str)]
```

See this **[demo](http://ideone.com/0nUNF8)**.

Comment: I was wondering where your original answer went. Where is the connection between the `if re.search` and the `re.sub`? I don't use re's much but I'd like to understand this one.

Comment: This regex is advanced and not easy one... `search` checks if the string contains `L_` or `R_` at the beginning or, `_L` or `_R` at the end, or `_L_` or `_R_` anywhere inside; `sub` takes care of replacement `L <-> R` if `search` found a match...